# Amplifier draining battery

Tags: chevrolet, audio, wiring

I have a 2005 Chevy Avalanche with a parasitic draw. I have it narrowed down to the factory bose amplifier and had already replaced it with no change in the current draw. I had disconnected the radio and no change as well as the rear seat audio controller, with no change. Any ideas out there? Would anybody have the pin layout for this model? I am pretty sure it is the premium sound with rear entertainment. 20 pins are used in the harness I pulled. How would I be able to test this at the harness?

Comment: Find the positive supply and control it with a relay so it only comes on with the engine running.

Comment: Unplug the amp in the back and see if you still get the drain.

Comment: Yes I had done that and the drain did go away. I am looking the find where the relay is now for the amp. There is a relay somewhere.

Comment: I tested at the connector which feeds power to the amp with it unplugged and there is still power in the wire when everything is suppose to be asleep.